# Update view inside custom adapter, after pressing the button

Tags: java, android, adapter

I need to update progress bar after i press the button inside my custom adapter.
Only when i declared view value as final i can do that. But it doesn't suit me.
What are the right solutions to do this ?
My custom adapter source:

```
public class DownloadListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements DownloadManagerListener{

    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Product> objects;
    View view;

    DownloadListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Product p = getProduct(position);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setProgress(p.size);

        Button btSet = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btSet);

        btSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //this does not work
                progressBar.setProgress(100);
                //this doesn't work too, it will work only when view will declared as final
                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                pb.setProgress(100);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnDownloadStarted(long taskId) {
        //This method should also have access to view
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    Product getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Product) getItem(position));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood when I read your code, you want to start download indicator (in this case, indicator is your progress bar). So you can try this way:

**1.** I assume that this is your DownloadManagerListener or you can change yours to this:

```
public interface DownloadManagerListener {

void OnDownloadStarted(long taskId, View view);
```

}

**2.** Change your button listener like this:

```
btSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ProgressBar progress = ((LinearLayout) v.getParent())
                        .findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    OnDownloadStarted(0, progress);

    }
});
```

In this I assumed that your layout (R.layout.item) like that:

```
<LinelearLayout>
...
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"/> 
...
<Button android:id="@+id/btSet"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**3.** Finally your method OnDownloadStarted like this:

```
public void OnDownloadStarted(long taskId, View view) {
    ProgressBar progressBar  = (ProgressBar) view;
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
}
```

### UPDATE 1:

Base on author comment. I suggest following point:

**1.** Remove View view; from member off class and in getview method. Because when list view is populated, view reference to last item that has been call getView. So view member of adapter class is meaningless.
**2.** Change class which like this:

public class DownloadListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements DownloadManagerListener{

```
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Product> objects;
HashMap<Integer, ProgressBar> mProductDownloaderMap = new HashMap<Integer, ProgressBar>();
```

**3.** Chang getView() method like this:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
}

Product p = getProduct(position);

progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

Button btSet = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btSet);

mProductDownloaderMap.put(position, progressBar);

btSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        OnDownloadStarted(position);// position is indicated taskID

    }
});
```

**4.** On your dowload method:

```
public void OnDownloadStarted(long taskId) {
    ProgressBar progressBar = mProductDownloaderMap.get(taskId);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    //Your download code here
}
```

***Please let me know if I missunderstand your code/your purpose!***

***Also dont forget to mark this is anwsers if my answers is right for your question***

***Hope that help!***

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, but it's not my own library. I mean this inteface i implemented from another lib. I can't edit interfaces and the line with the call of these interfaces.

Comment: Ok, so how do you know which item in list view start download? Does it base on taskId? for example taskId = 1 which is start download item with position 1 in your listview?

Comment: now I begin to understand that I had misunderstood the work of my adapter.Ok, If it will base on ID, how can I get access to the view wich i needed from interface method inside my adapter class? Or it's not the best idea to realize this ?

Answer (score 0):

The view variable is global in the class so no need to make it final.
You should make the progressBar as final and change its progress inside button onClick method

Comment: it's work for me, but it's also doesn't suit me. It's work when OnClickListener declare inline, but in my case, my adapter implemented listner interface also. And his methods must have access to view too.
In my example i simplifided, but now i expend source. What should I do now? When i added interface and OnDownloadStarted method ?

Comment: Yes I see, the view is global so the OnDownloadStarted will have access to it, so no need to change it. Just the progressbar that should be final inside the getView method so that it can be accessed inside the onClick()

Comment: In the OnDownloadStarted i have no access to progress bar field. Because it declared as final in getView method, and it invisible for me inside OnDownloadStarted method.
i tried to declared it one more time inside OnDownloadStarted as: 
final ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            pb.setProgress(100);
but it also doesn't working..

Comment: Then try to make your progress bar too global and initialize in inside getView so that it will be visible to all methods.

Comment: if i make my progress bar global, i can't do it final, becouse final requared inline initialized. This is the main problem.

Comment: i didn't mean to make it final while it's global. in the global variables add
ProgressBar pb; then inside your getView method add: pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 like this it will be visible to all methods